# type viewcontroller does not conform to protocol uitableviewdatasource

Tags: ios, uitableview

I already done the same tableview in another view but in this one could not work. I'm also looking for an solution but i don't know what doesn't work

class HistoryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

var date = ["ciao", "muori"]
var place = ["aaaa"]



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableview.dataSource = self
    tableview.delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func tableview(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HistoryCell
    cell.placeLabel.text = place[indexPath.row]
    cell.dateLabel.text = date[indexPath.row]
    return cell

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

}
```

someone could help me?

Comment: is it possible for you to share the file?

Comment: You implemented `tableview:cellForRowIndexPath:` instead of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 3):

- Goto Issue Navigator (<kbd>⌘4</kbd>).
- Open the disclosure triangle next to the error message.
- Implement the missing required methods which are displayed beneath the error message.

And use code completion to avoid those typos.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a mistake in the method name: you have to implement `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` not `tableview:cellForRowIndexPath:`. Here is a correct implementation :

```
class HistoryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    var date = ["ciao", "muori"]
    var place = ["aaaa"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableview.dataSource = self
        tableview.delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! HistoryCell
        cell.placeLabel.text = place[indexPath.row]
        cell.dateLabel.text = date[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath  indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

and

```
func tableView(tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int)
```

are inserted inside class {} brackets.